# Image of a subspace under the induced homology map: does $f(X)\subset Y$ imply $f_*H_1(X)\subset H_1(Y)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Assume we have topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ and let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a continuous map.
Does it follow that the image of the induced homomorphism $f_*: H_1(X)$ is a submodule of $H_1(Y)$? In other words, does $f(X)\subset Y$ imply $f_*H_1(X)\subset H_1(Y)$?

I'm a bit confused because we know that $X\subset Y$ does certainly not imply that $H_1(X)\subset H_1(Y)$ but I don't know whether $f_*H_1(X)\subset H_1(Y)$. I checked the literature but wasn't succesfull in finding an answer.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why is the second case not the same as the first with $f$ equal to the inclusion map? There are always maps on homology, but they certainly needn’t be injective.

Comment: This is true just because $f_\ast$ is a homomorphism. If $f$ is a hom. $A\to B$, $f(A)$ is a subgroup of $B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_*$ is a map $H_1(X)\to H_1(Y)$, and so the image is clearly a subgroup of $H_1(Y)$. What you wrote in the second paragraph is that if $X\subseteq Y$, the map induced by the inclusion $i:X\to Y$ might not be injective. So the image might not be isomorphic to $H_1(X)$. (still, the image, whatever it is, is clearly contained in $H_1(Y)$)

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it's just the very basic property of maps in general that for any map $f$ the subset relation $A\subset B$ implies $f(A)\subset f(B)$ and images of groups being subgroups. So $f_*H_1(X)$ is certainly a subgroup of $H_1(Y)$, right?

Comment: @Zest The property we are using is that if $f:A\to B$ is a function then $f(A)\subseteq B$. We don't need $A$ to be a subset of $B$ here. $B$ is the range of $f$. And yes, the image of a group homomorphism is a subgroup.